# Report Formula - print number based on picklist value

Tags: reporting, report-formula

I have problems creating a report formula. I would like to express the following:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status_Picklist__c, 'green'), 100, 20)
```

I have a picklist `Status_Picklist__c` and if that picklist is set to `green`, then I want the formula field to show `100`, otherwise `20`. This, however does not seem to work unfortunately, because `Status_Picklist__c` doesn't even seem to be available for selection in the report.

Any ideas how I can manage this requirement without the creation of a new field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not define such condition in report-formula. Report-formulas are designed to calculate [sum, min, max, average](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=building_custom_summary_formulas.htm&type=5) values across the number of records. In order to get some value based on values of fields on concrete record you have to create custom formula field on object.